# Difference between OnLoad method and Load event?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, load

What is the difference between `OnLoad` method and `Load` event? I am developing WinForm controls.
Should I register to `Load` event or override the `OnLoad` method? What are the advantages and the disadvantages of each one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd go for overriding `OnLoad`, so you spare the CPU cycles to invoke the event handler.

The general pattern is to override a method, if you inherit from a control; otherwise, subscribe to the event.

But remember to call the base class' `OnLoad` method, because that's where the `Load` event invoked.

Comment: According to Microsoft, overloading the OnLoad method is the '.. preferred technique for handling the event in a **derived** class' (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload.aspx)

Comment: @TroyMoon Isn't this what Thomas said?

Answer (score 6):

OnLoad method is the one that raises Load event. It's a standard pattern in framework classes, and a generally recommended one - for any event `Foo`, you have a virtual protected method `OnFoo` which raises that event; and no other method of the class raises the event directly, but always calls `OnFoo`.

If you need to handle the event on `this`, it's usually both easier and faster to override `OnFoo`.

Answer (score 0):

OnLoad is the default event handler used in VB.NET to handle the Load event.  I typically override this method when I need to attach code to the load event.  There are also default functions for the other [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) events: OnPreRender, OnInit, etc.

Comment: Oops...  Just realized you were asking about winform.  Disreguard page life cycle link.  Same applies though.

Comment: Also, it is the same in other .NET languages, such as C# (the .NET framework itself was largely coded in C#).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit of clarity to the existing answers, an event handler is something that 'waits' for the event to trigger. This requires some CPU overhead as you need to have a thread 'listening' for the event to occur. This would be something `like MainWindow_Load()` in a winforms application. However, **since we already know 'when' the event will happen (it happens as soon as the form loads), there's no reason to actually use an event handler**. It's not like a click event where we have no clue when the user might click in which case you really do need an event handler. So instead of holding up some CPU processing, we can create a method in the class which simply forces the Load event to occur which is called invoking the Load event.

This is why it's preferable to use the OnLoad method when possible, in situations where you always know when the event is going to happen.