# changing button BackColor, C++ Visual Studio 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

My first post.
I'm experimenting with windows form and C++.
I have some (basic) questions. The goal so far is to write a program that check if a certain hardware is plugged in through an USB port, but before I get to the real work I wanted to finish the GUI that will inform whether or not the hardware was found.
So I have a standard form (Form1.h),  then I have the cpp class in which the main method resides(usbStatus.cpp) and another cpp file(connection.cpp) in which I'm planning to put the code to search for the wanted hardware. Right at start up the form is displaying a statusButton set with background color RED and a statusLabel saying "Searching hardware". Then I would like that when the other code (not written yet) is finished searching for the hardware the button background color changes to green (if HW found) and label to "Hardware  found". Well... nothing happens. I have checked with traces and the code is processed but without visible result. I have tried Invalidate() and Refresh() without success.

The very little I have right now looks pretty much like this:

Form1.h

```
namespace usbStatus{

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //

        }
    ...

    void InitializeComponent(void)
        {

    ...
    this->statusButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripButton());
    this->statusLabel = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripLabel());
    ....

    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
    ...
    }
```

At the end of the file I've added the following method

```
public: void Form1::UpdateStatusElements(Color color) 
{
    statusButton->BackColor = color;
    if (color == System::Drawing::Color::Green){
        //statusprogressBar->Enabled = false;
        statusLabel->Text = "Hardware found";
    } else {
        ...
```

usbStatus.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include "Connection.h"

using namespace UsbStatus;


[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    //Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    Form1 ^mainWindow = gcnew Form1();
    Application::Run(mainWindow);

if(Connection::GetStatus()) 
    mainWindow->UpdateStatusElements(System::Drawing::Color::Green);
else
    //mainWindow->UpdateStatusElements(System::Drawing::Color::Red);
delete mainWindow;
return 0;
}
```

Connection.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Form1.h"



ref class Connection
{
    private:
        static void CheckStatus();
        static void SetStatus(bool connected);
        static bool hwConnected;

    public:
        static bool GetStatus();

};
```

Connection.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Connection.h"

using namespace UsbStatus;

...

bool Connection::GetStatus()
{
    CheckStatus();
    return true;
    //return hwConnected;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `Application::Run(mainWindow);` is a **blocking** call. This mean it will not return until your dialog has terminated. Internally it will run the [windows message loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381405). So the subsequent calls will executed *after* your dioalog closes... I think this is not intended.

You need to move your check into the Form1 class. Either use the [`Load`-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) (or override [`OnLoad`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096569/difference-between-onload-method-and-load-event) for this or you a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) in order to regulary check for the state and update your UI. You can add a `Timer` in the Dialog-Editor by dropping it from the UI-Elements into your Form.

See also: [Winforms Timer for Dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174733/winforms-timer-for-dummies)

Comment: Hi Jochen and thank you for your time. You are right, I moved the if/else before the Run command (just for testing you suggestion) and it actually update as I was trying to do.

Comment: I have this feeling that I should not put any logic in the Form classes more than the really essential needed to update the GUI, is it unnecessary to think so or should I stick to that?

Comment: A better solution is to separate the logic via an interface! Then you can implement the logic in your own class and just pass the interface into the form.